# Getting a parent's child to find parent's child text width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to get the width of the text in order to calculate the width of the rect which acts as the background. I am don't know how to traverse to the parent "nodeGroup" and then get the child text width, hoping to get some help. Pseudo code below.

**Code using to try to get the width (doesn't work)**

```
nodeGroups.selectAll('rect')
    .attr("width", function(d) {      
      let width = this.parentNode.select('text').getComputedTextLength; //??     
      console.log(width);
      return width;
    })
```

**With the error:**
this.parentNode.select is not a function

**Here is the basic structure of the nodeGroup:**

```
  <g class="nodeGroup">
      <circle class="node" r="15" fill="#67b14f" cx="163.66683334043782" cy="25.26573226107303">
      </circle>
      <rect fill="#676767" text-anchor="middle" class="labelBack" height="20" x="179.66683334043782" y="15.26573226107303">
      </rect>
      <text class="label" x="187.66683334043782" y="29.26573226107303">
        GET MY WIDTH <--- ?????
      </text>
  </g>
```

Comment: Would getting the text's binding box be easier: http://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/8745933 or https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929

Comment: @RyanMorton happy to use binding box, but I don't know how to iterate through each parent's text to calculate that. I got an error when I tried getBBox() using  as well as this.parentNode.select is not the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want to use the bbox approach for this as suggested in the comments.

`parentNode` returns the DOM element, not a D3 selection, so

```
this.parentNode.select('text')
```

won't work, you need to use:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode)
```

Then, you can select the text element, and get its bbox from the DOM element itself (not the d3 selection):

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).select(text).node().getBBox();
```

Then from there you can get the width with `bbox.width`. Of course, you don't need to use d3 selections for the intermediate steps, but as you've started down this path, I've continued with it for the first snippet below:

```js
var data = ["Short String","A Longer String"];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");
  
var g = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i) { 
     return "translate("+[20,i*20+20]+")";
  });
  
g.append("rect")
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill","yellow");
  
g.append("text")
 .text(function(d) { return d; })
 .attr("y", 18);

g.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("width",function() {
     let parentSelection = d3.select(this.parentNode)
     
     let bbox = parentSelection.select("text").node().getBBox();
  
     let width = bbox.width;
     
     return width;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Better Approach**

But, things get easier (and faster) without d3 for the intermediate steps. If your rectangle is the nearest sibling before the text, then you can use `nextSibling` (as `this` refers to the rectangle, the next element is the text):

```js
var data = ["Short String","A Longer String"];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");
  
var g = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i) { 
     return "translate("+[20,i*20+20]+")";
  });
  
g.append("rect")
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill","yellow");
  
g.append("text")
 .text(function(d) { return d; })
 .attr("y", 18);

g.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("width",function() {
     return this.nextSibling.getBBox().width;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good answer, as always... however, you don't need to get the element, select it and get the element again, it can be done in 1 step: `return this.parentNode.children[1].getBBox().width;`. look here: https://jsfiddle.net/xqy09qLu/

Comment: Perhaps I can bold part 2? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hahaha, sorry! I didn't read it! Yes, creating a bold title (like **Solution 2**) can help blind people like me.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll hide the first snippet, and format the visibility of the second half a bit.

Comment: Good, sorry again. On a separate note, that's why I normally select "hide snippet by default" in the snippet, when the code is too big people sometimes don't scroll down to the end (as I did here)...